# Calling stored procedure inside View in Netezza

Tags: netezza

Can we call a stored procedure inside the View in Netezza?

I am doing Oracle to Netezza Migration.

We have a view in Netezza that uses CONNECT BY ROOT.

To replicate CONNECT BY ROOT, we have written a stored procedure.

How to call that stored procedure from a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While stored procedures can be called with a SELECT form, I don't think they can be called that way from within a view.